# G-WAN: is it possible to turn off microcaching?

Tags: caching, configuration, g-wan

According to its [website](http://gwan.com/faq#cache) G-WAN uses microcaching that lasts 200ms. The only way to prevent microcaching mentioned on the website is to use a changing query parameter.

I'd like to use G-WAN. The problem is my home page is a newsfeed that's personalized for each user. So even though everyone goes to the same URL (mydomain.com) the content would be completely different for each person, just like facebook or twitter.

Obviously caching would not work in this case. Is there any way to turn off caching?

Comment: If your contents are different for each user then you are *either* using **URI parameters** or **cookies** - and in both cases caching is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about the microcaching, as far as I got from other answers so far, it only applies if the used portions of the requests stay the same, and as you'll probably use cookies to identify users, that portion would change for every user, so that the microcaching would only apply on a per user base, e.g. one user might get the same cached version if he repeats the query in that timeframe, but user A should not get the same reply as user B, not matter how close those requests are to each other.

Comment: Are you sure G-WAN's microcaching looks at cookies? The FAQ I linked to said specifically that the way to prevent is to use query parameters, that is, to use unique URL's. It doesn't mention cookies at all.

Comment: I'm not sure as I'm not the author of GWAN, but I've been using it for quite some time now and when the forums where still online I remember a couple of people also asking about microcaching, and the answer back then was along those lines as far as I remember. And about FAQ/Manual: Unfortunately those aren't always up to date/in sync with the server, so you might wanna look through the examples as well - those always seem to be more current.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to get access to the old forum again - they had it online for a while in a read only state, but I'm unable to find it anymore, so what I posted might not be correct. Therefor I suggest you wait another day, Gil normally seems to answer questions within about a day. If it turns out my answer is wrong, I'll gladly delete it of course. Till then it's probably better than nothing ;)

Comment: I suggest griffin's answer is accepted as this is clearly the right answer.